# Is it possible to enable NTLM for only some controllers in ASP.NET WEB.API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

An ASP.NET WEB.API self hosted service is setup as follows:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("http://localhost:9060")
                {
                    ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm
                };
```

There's a requirement to disable NTLM for some endpoints that this service exposes.

Is that possible?

Comment: What about [AllowAnonymous] attribute for such controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Not a particularly elegant solution but it's possible to self-host twice in the same process when listening on different ports. One can use NTLM and the other can accept anonymous requests.

[This MSDN blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hongmeig1/archive/2012/05/11/how-to-support-multiple-authentication-in-self-host.aspx) from Hongmei Ge suggests that it is possible in .Net Framework 4.5 onwards to support multiple authentication schemes in a single host.